# Displaying text on camera feed

Tags: text, readability, overlay, transparency

I am developing a iOS app, for which the main screen is used to scan a QR code. I want the camera to cover the screen, and at the same time display several text elements.

My main strategy so far has been to use semi-transparency. The top banner uses a semi-transparent background, and all the other UI elements have semi-transparent color.

My main worry is that the UI elements should be readable under both bright and dark lighting. At the moment, the text is not very readable with a bright camera feed.

What are "tricks" to make UI elements more readable when overlaid on top of a camera feed? Note that I want to keep the UI clean and minimal.

[image]

Comment: Can you also include a version of the screenshot with a high contrast background, because the image you have doesn't really illustrate the problem well.  I suggest something like this:  http://i.imgur.com/WHzigr8.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: Try a visual treatment like this?]  by using a semi transparent black panel. doesn't matter if the background is too light or too dark.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need the entire screen to be transparent? If not, you can easily change the placement of the text to be on a less transparent background.

Answer (score 0):

## Text Outline


Give your text a text outline effect or border of .5px. So that it will be readable.

**Option 2:**
You can for dark grey fonts.

*Reason:* QR codes will be in all colors except white and the QR code will be only covered only in that target area leaving background to be white.